# Dynamically enable and disable textbox Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, dynamic, textbox

I am trying to achieve the following behaviour:
Mutually exclusive textboxes (Entry labels), that follow rules like

- Only two boxes out of 3 can have text entered at once (content must be deleted to re-enable the third)
- Filling one box disables a set of subjects.
- (Not required, nice to have) A tooltip that comes up when hovering over a disabled textbox explaining why it is locked.

My idea is to have a 'check' function on the 'command' attribute of an 'Entry' label, so that when each textbox is edited, the code checks all the specified 'cause' textboxes for their value and, if some conditions are met, a set of 'effect' textboxes are disabled.

I believe I would also have to forward declare all the Entry labels, then declare the function, then configure the Entry labels to have this function, and then pack them onto the screen.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or at least a way that avoids the forward declaration requirement?

Thanks, and feel free to request more information!

edit:
Here is an example implementation

```
entry1 = tk.Entry (window) 

entry2 = tk.Entry (window) 

def shut_x():
    if entry1.get() != "":
        entry2.configure(state="disabled")
    else:
        entry2.configure(state="normal")

entry1.configure(command=shut_x())

canvas1.create_window(650, 140, window=entry1)
canvas1.create_window(650, 340, window=entry2)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you literally just asking if there is a better way? If so, it would help if you showed an actual implementation rather than just a description of the implementation. Also, what do you mean by "the 'command' attribute of an 'Entry' label"? Neither Entry widgets nor Label widgets have a "command" attribute.

Comment: I have added an example bit of code. And to clarify, yes im asking if there is a better way as this seems really clunky to me. Furthermore, the documentation at "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm" says thart entry does have a command attribute. Perhaps we are thinking of different things?

Comment: @Frogglet Add a `StringVar` to the entry and trace that variable.

Comment: @Frogglet: that documentation is wrong.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well I used it before and it was working, but was not optimal as it was running the function on the label's creation aswell. In any case, I used TheLizzard's solution so I'm all good now :D

Comment: _"Well I used it before and it was working,"_ - that is impossible. The `Entry` and `Label` widgets do not have a `command` option. You can easily verify this by trying to define `command` when creating either of those widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def shut_x(*args):
    if entry1.get() != "":
        entry2.config(state="disabled")
    else:
        entry2.config(state="normal")

root = tk.Tk()

tk_variable = tk.StringVar(root)
tk_variable.trace("w", shut_x)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tk_variable)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This creates a `StringVar` variable and attaches it to `entry1`. It also traces that variable with the callback function being `shut_x`.

For the 3 entries that you requested (where the user can only write in 2 of them):

```py
import tkinter as tk

def shut_x(*args):
    number_of_entries_with_text = 0
    number_of_entries_with_text += entry1.get() != ""
    number_of_entries_with_text += entry2.get() != ""
    number_of_entries_with_text += entry3.get() != ""
    # Check if some how you managed to insert text in all 3 of the entries:
    # It should never happen
    assert number_of_entries_with_text <= 2, "An internal error"
    if number_of_entries_with_text == 2:
        if entry1.get() == "":
            entry1.config(state="disabled")
        elif entry2.get() == "":
            entry2.config(state="disabled")
        elif entry3.get() == "":
            entry3.config(state="disabled")
    elif number_of_entries_with_text < 2:
        if entry1.get() == "":
            entry1.config(state="normal")
        if entry2.get() == "":
            entry2.config(state="normal")
        if entry3.get() == "":
            entry3.config(state="normal")

root = tk.Tk()

tk_variable_entry1 = tk.StringVar(root)
tk_variable_entry1.trace("w", shut_x)

tk_variable_entry2 = tk.StringVar(root)
tk_variable_entry2.trace("w", shut_x)

tk_variable_entry3 = tk.StringVar(root)
tk_variable_entry3.trace("w", shut_x)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tk_variable_entry1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tk_variable_entry2)
entry2.pack()

entry3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tk_variable_entry3)
entry3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. This worked for me! Now to spend hours hardcoding all my conditions :P

Comment: @Frogglet It should take more than 10 min. I will also do it (and update my answer)

Comment: @Frogglet Done I implemented the 3 entries. For the tooltip window thing, you will have to Google that because I am not an expert in that.

Comment: Thankyou very much! My version was a lot more clunky :)

Comment: @Frogglet No problem. Well mine isn't the best either. I could have used a list and iterated over it. But if it works, it works.